# How to get relation of relation Count in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

i have laravel models

Category: id,name

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany(PostCategory::class,'category_id','id');
}
```

PostCategory : post_id, category_id

```
public function post(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class,'post_id');
}
```

POST: id, ..so on

```
public function solutions(){
    return $this->hasMany(PostSolution::class,'post_id','id');
 }
```

I need to get count of all posts fall under a category and also solutions under one category.. there is no direct relation of category and solution so how to get count of solutions in one category.

```
$categories = Category::withCount('posts')->get();
```

Comment: Are you sure, that a post category belongs to a single post? Shouldn't it be the other way around (or that a post belongs to many post categories)?

Comment: Thanks Has Many Through is working!

Comment: The person who answered this has deleted their comment so i am not able to upvote.

Comment: @Basharmal  yes you are right!  single post belongs to many categories

Answer (score 1):

I think use hasManyThrough relation

```
// Category Class

public function solutions()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(PostSolution::class, Post::class);
}

// Then get the data in the same old manner
$categories = Category::->withCount('posts')->get();
```

I hope this will help